# Symfony - How do I handle paths which have existing folders of the same name in /public/

Tags: symfony, routes

I have a folder /public/press/ which contains PDF files for press downloads. 
Now I would like to create a new page with the path /press/

What happens is, that the server finds the existing folder and returns a "Forbidden" message, instead of mapping the folder name to index.php

*routes.xaml:*

```
press:
    path: /press
    controller: App\Controller\StaticpagesController::press
```

*.htaccess:*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Strangly, if I test with Symfony´s build-in Development server, everything works well. When using Apache I get the forbidden message for the existing folder.

Comment: see in apache error log files: e.a. /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: I believe it all comes down to directory index access. apache provides that functionality, that you theoretically can access a directory index (`/press` in this case) and list all files. If you remove the line with `!-d` this could already be enough to trigger the url to be rewritten ...

Comment: @Jakumi - I have already tried to remove the !-d condition, but this lead to a redirect loop.

Comment: The redirect loop is then between /press and /press/

Comment: well the easiest solution would be to just rename the effing directory to something that doesn't appear as a route. otherwise you can probably disable the trailing slash redirect via http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash somewhere.

Comment: @Jakumi - I think this would be a good answer. I will try it.